# Simulate mouse-clicking a widget in Python Gtk3+

Tags: python, gtk3

A Python 3 and Gtk 3.22.5 application responds to a global key binding, thanks to the [Keybinder](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Keybinder-3.0/index.html) library. Currently it invokes a simple callback:

```
def keybinder_callback(self, keystr, user_data):
    print("Handling", keystr, user_data)
```

Elsewhere in the application is a `Gtk.Window` that contains a `Gtk.MenuBar`. The `keybinder_callback` needs to activate the menu bar as if the user had clicked the mouse on it.

(it's a very basic dock-type application rather than one with a typical application window)

I have tried sending a signal to a menu item:

```
self.menubar.get_children()[0].emit("activate-item")
```

without any joy. I also tried faking a button press

```
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
fake_input(display,X.ButtonPress,1)
```

which also had no effect, but feels like the wrong way to do it anyway. I thought sending a signal would be more appropriate.

**Can a widget be activated programmatically as if a user mouse-clicked on it?**

(it doesn't have to be a simulated mouse-click - it just needs to activate and focus the widget in the same way that a mouse-click would)

---

I have written an [example](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/db6bf5247058e32ffa5d794af37b80a3) that has a [`keybinder_callback`](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/db6bf5247058e32ffa5d794af37b80a3#file-menu2-py-L80) like this:

```
def keybinder_callback(self, keystr, user_data):
  print("Handling", keystr, user_data)
  print("Event time:", Keybinder.get_current_event_time())
  activate_the_menu()
```

I need to add some command to that function that will `activate_the_menu`.

I have tried many things, including capturing real events (by monitoring with `xev`) and simulating them (  `ENTER_NOTIFY` and `FOCUS_CHANGE`), by injecting them into `Gdk.main_do_event`.

I've tried calling `menu.popup`, `menu.popup_at_widget`, `menubar.select_item` and other numerous things. All to no avail.

Running out of ideas, I've even dusted off my old Xlib book...

Incidentally, whilst not a proper solution, this works from a shell:

```
$ xdotool mousemove 1605 10 click 1 mousemove restore
```

but not reliably from the `keybinder_callback`:

```
run("xdotool mousemove %d 10 click 1 mousemove restore" %
            (self.get_position().root_x+5) , shell=True)
```

Comment: Take a look at [`GtkMenu.popup_at_widget`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkMenu.html#gtk-menu-popup-at-widget), but be careful, I almost froze my PC while playing around with it. Not really sure what happened, but after the menu popped up I couldn't close the program anymore.

Comment: Well I tried `self.menu.popup_at_widget(self,Gdk.Gravity.STATIC,Gdk.Gravity.STATIC,None)` but got `Warning: g_object_set_data: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things, I found that this works.

```
import Xlib
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
import time

def keybinder_callback(self, keystr, user_data):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    x = self.get_position().root_x+5
    display = Display()
    mpos = display.screen().root.query_pointer()._data
    display.screen().root.warp_pointer(x,5)
    display.sync()
    fake_input(display,X.ButtonPress,1, X.CurrentTime, X.NONE, x, 5)
    display.sync()
    fake_input(display,X.ButtonRelease,1)
    display.screen().root.warp_pointer(mpos['root_x'],
                                       mpos['root_y'])
    display.sync()
```

I found that the time delay was necessary to avoid this error:

```
Gdk-CRITICAL **: Window 0x1e7c660 has not been made visible in GdkSeatGrabPrepareFunc
```